# Canvas drawText with gradient color

Tags: android, android-canvas

Is that possible to draw text on Canvas with gradient color in Andorid?

For example, draw letter A with top part is red while bottom part is blue?

Thanks

Comment: see Paint.setShader() method

Comment: Any example? A more complete answer is welcomed, so that I can accept ur ans

Comment: create a new LinearGradient which is a Shader, so you can use Paint.setShader() and then call Canvas.drawText with that modified Paint